# Creating duplicate Google spreadsheets that filter data from a master sheet and update rows on master sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Basically, I have a huge list of data on Google Docs spreadsheets, and a bunch of people that read it. They are not tech savvy. I am trying to create duplicate sheets on a Google spreadsheet that are filtered copies of a master sheet, in order to increase readability for the other collaborators, and that when a row is modified on one of these filtered sheets, will update the corresponding row on the master sheet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

[How to automatically pull data between different Google Spreadsheets](http://davefoord.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/how-to-automatically-pull-data-between-different-google-spreadsheets/):

> There is a function called **ImportRange** that allows you to pull
>   data out of one sheet and into another. This can be really useful, if
>   for example you have a spreadsheet that you are using to collaborate
>   with others, and then somewhere along the line you want another person
>   to be able to see some of the data in the sheet but not all of it.
>   e.g. if you are using this to track student grades, you could have a
>   master sheet that you and other tutors can see all of, you could then
>   create a separate sheet for each student, and pull through only the
>   data that refers to them (you then share that sheet with the student)
>   and they have a live constantly updating record of what they have
>   achieved etc.

Comment: ImportRange is a live link, so data changed in the master sheet will "immediately" show in the linked sheet. The linked spreadsheet has to have permission to see the data in the master sheet.